# Data defined symbol rotation for a categorized renderer

Tags: qgis, style

I have a CSV File with coordinates and a certain column called azimuth. Azimuth field can have any value from 0 to 360 degrees.  I want to plot the points as triangles, but rotate them depending upon the azimuth column.

I understand that , there is a option to categorize the style. However, I have to go to each category and [image: Category Values] change the rotation manually.

How can I make the rotation value read directly from the Azimuth

Answer (score 5):

You're almost there but you need to edit the properties of the base symbol, see blue markings in your screenshot:

[image]

Pick the azimuth column from the list of available attribute fields in the data-defined override menu.

Comment: Hi, actually the problem is , if I have hundred rows of data, then for each symbol I have to enter the azimuth value individually. I want the "Rotation" data to be read from the column named "Azimuth". Note that , Azimuth can be have any value from 0 to 360

Comment: Gothcha !!! I wasn't able to understand your reply first, now that I have, its working like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Left-click the icon to the right of your *Rotation* option and select **"Edit..."**:

[image: Style rotation]

Then type in your column name surrounded by double quotes (eg. "azimuth"). Hopefully this should set the rotation of each feature automatically.